# Postgres LIKE '...%' doesn't use index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table in which I want to search by a prefix of the primary key. The primary key has values like `03.000221.1`, `03.000221.2`, `03.000221.3`, etc. and I want to retrieve all that begin with `03.000221.`.

My first thought was to filter with `LIKE '03.000221.%'`, thinking Postgres would be smart enough to look up `03.000221.` in the index and perform a range scan from that point. But no, this performs a sequential scan.

```
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..253626.34 rows=78 width=669)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ...  (cost=0.00..252618.54 rows=32 width=669)
         Filter: ((id ~~ '03.000221.%'::text)
 JIT:
   Functions: 2
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

If I do an equivalent operation using a plain `>=` and `<` range, e. g. `id >= '03.000221.' and id < '03.000221.Z'` it does use the index:

```
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ... on ...  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=669)
   Index Cond: ((id >= '03.000221.'::text) AND (id < '03.000221.Z'::text))
```

But this is dirtier and it seems to me that Postgres should be able to deduce it can do an equivalent index range lookup with `LIKE`. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL will do this if you are build the index with [text_pattern_ops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) operator, or if you are using the C collation.

If you are using some random other collation, PostgreSQL can't deduce much of anything about it. Observe this, in the very common "en_US.utf8" collation.

```
select * from (values ('03.000221.1'), ('03.0002212'), ('03.000221.3')) f(x) order by x;
      x      
-------------
 03.000221.1
 03.0002212
 03.000221.3
```

Which then naturally leads to this wrong answer with your query:

```
select * from (values ('03.000221.1'), ('03.0002212'), ('03.000221.3')) f(id)
    where ((id >= '03.000221.'::text) AND (id < '03.000221.Z'::text))
     id      
-------------
 03.000221.1
 03.0002212
 03.000221.3
```

Comment: For the given values, `collate "C"` is probably the best choice

Comment: I'm using C.UTF-8, which apparently isn't C enough. Thanks!

Comment: @ToniCárdenas  I've never understood the difference between C and C.UTF-8.  I think maybe C is implemented internally as a special case, while C.UTF-8 is outsourced to glibc.  It probably could use the index over C.UTF-8 and get the right answer, it just doesn't know that it could.