# Can partitioning be used for LIKE queries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, partitioning

I have huge words table which I'm running LIKE query on:

```sql
create table words
(
  id   int,
  word varchar
)
```

It works pretty long. Index doesn't help a lot, so I'm trying to partition it by `word` column:

```sql
create table words
(
  id   int,
  word varchar
) partition by RANGE (word);

CREATE TABLE words_1 PARTITION OF words
  FOR VALUES FROM ('a') TO ('n');

CREATE TABLE words_2 PARTITION OF words
  FOR VALUES FROM ('n') TO ('z');
```

NOTE: Actually I'm planning to make 1 partition for each letter. Use only 2 of them for example simplicity.

So partitioning seems to work OK with equality and gt/lt operators:

```sql
explain
select * from words where word = 'abc'
```

```
Seq Scan on words_1 words  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)
  Filter: ((word)::text = 'abc'::text)
```

```sql
explain
select * from words where word >= 'nth'
```

```
Seq Scan on words_2 words  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=423 width=36)
  Filter: ((word)::text >= 'nth'::text)
```

But on LIKE queries it keeps scanning both partitions:

```sql
explain
select * from words where word LIKE 'abc%'
```

```
Append  (cost=0.00..51.81 rows=12 width=36)
  ->  Seq Scan on words_1  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)
        Filter: ((word)::text ~~ 'abc'::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on words_2  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)
        Filter: ((word)::text ~~ 'abc'::text)
```

Is there a way to make partitioning work on LIKE queries?

Maybe is there another way to achieve what i want?

Comment: LIKE 'abc' gives same result. Anyway, like without % doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Do you need an id? Could the word be the primary key?

Comment: Could you show us the sort of slow queries you're doing on this table?

Comment: Try an `explain analyze` to make sure the table statistics are up to date.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to describe entire picture. Table is a tokenized text field of another table and used as a kind of an index for word-based search. ID - is foreign key here. Query itself joins few more tables. `explain analyze` says scan of this table takes 25 ms out of 27

Comment: Use [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to make a demonstration, please. How many rows are in this table? Could you use Postgresql's existing text search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised it doesn't just work, at least in the C collation. But I can verify that it doesn't.

You could rewrite the query manually the same way `word like 'abc%'` sometimes gets rewritten:

```
explain analyze
select * from words where word >='abc' and word <'abd'
```

But this is only guaranteed to give the same answer in the C collation.

By the way, you should check partition pruning with EXPLAIN ANALYZE.  It is possible for the partition pruning to only happen at run time, in which case all partitions still show up in the plan EXPLAIN plan. (But run-time pruning isn't the case here, I checked)

For non-C collation, you can use text_pattern_ops as Laurenz alludes to.  As long as you spell it correctly, unlike my first attempt.

```
create table words2
(
  id   int,
  word varchar
) partition by RANGE (word text_pattern_ops);
```

But then you still need to rewrite the query in order to make the partition pruning happen.

```
explain analyze
select * from words2 where word like 'abc%' and word ~>=~ 'abc' and word  ~<~ 'abd';
```

You need both the LIKE and the inequality range, because the range alone might return false positives. (I don't know exactly when it might do that, but since the planner is worried about, I figure that worry is well-founded)

Comment: With collations other than C, you should be able to use `text_pattern_ops` in `PARTITION BY`. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, that works.  see edit.  I had just typed the operator name wrong and assumed the error meant it wouldn't work at all.  It still doesn't work with just the LIKE though, you need the manual intervention.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your results. Your queries use an index, even with only a handful of rows. Make sure your tables have been [analyzed](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html) and run your queries with `explain analyze`.

---

An improved table design would drop the `id` and use the word as a primary key, assuming they're unique. I've added about 1000 words and analyzed the table.

```
create table words ( word text primary key );

copy words(word) from '/Users/schwern/tmp/words.txt';

analyze words;
```

All of your queries do an index-only scan.

The default B-Tree index can do exact matches (`words = 'this'`), trailing wildcards (`words like 'this%'`) and ordering. We can improve this further adding a [Gist index using trigram ops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX).

```
create index word_gin_idx on words using gist(word gist_trgm_ops);
```

Now queries such as `word like '%this%'` will use the Gist index.

Comment: planning to consider GIST & pg_trgm as another option after dealing with partitioning. just wondering, can partitioning be an option at all?

Comment: problem is not in index using rather in the partition scanning. any string, that matches `abc%` pattern is greater than `a` and less than `n` which are used as partition range. so questions is: why can't LIKE query determine exact partition to scan?

Comment: @zoryamba The best a partition will do is take you from scanning all words to scanning all words in a partition, and only for very particular queries. You still need indexes. I don't know why `like` is scanning all tables, but I also don't know why it isn't using your index. We need more information.

Comment: found why it doesn't use index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422684/postgres-like-doesnt-use-index

so it's not the question. question is about like and partitioning

Comment: @zoryamba That doesn't seem correct. Your question shows none of your queries using the index, even a simple `word = 'this'`. A btree should be sufficient for all the questions, but it isn't working for you. If we can't reproduce your problem, we can't say why `like` isn't acting smarter about your partitions. We need more detail, something is missing from your question. Preferably a demonstration in dbfiddle.

Comment: I excluded index from example for simplicity. It's not the question about index

Comment: @zoryamba Ah ha, you have no indexes. Thank you, now it is clear.

Comment: Yeah, with index it scans btree for both partitions as well

Comment: @zoryamba Partition pruning must not be smart enough. Might be worth [reporting to PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bug-reporting.html) or asking on [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).